# Convert this SQL query to Codeigniter Active Record

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, select, activerecord

This is the query that I need to convert

```
SELECT pdg_matriculas.id_matricula, aluno.nome_aluno, pdg_serie.nome_serie, pdg_turma.nome_turma, aluno.status_aluno, pdg_matriculas.ano_letivo
FROM pdg_matriculas, pdg_serie, pdg_turma, aluno
WHERE pdg_matriculas.id_aluno = aluno.id_aluno
AND pdg_matriculas.id_serie = pdg_serie.id_serie
AND pdg_matriculas.id_turma = pdg_turma.id_turma
ORDER BY `aluno`.`nome_aluno` ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I tried to use direct query, It did not work.

```
$this->db->select('SELECT pdg_matriculas.id_matricula, aluno.nome_aluno, pdg_serie.nome_serie, pdg_turma.nome_turma, aluno.status_aluno, pdg_matriculas.ano_letivo
FROM pdg_matriculas, pdg_serie, pdg_turma, aluno
WHERE pdg_matriculas.id_aluno = aluno.id_aluno
AND pdg_matriculas.id_serie = pdg_serie.id_serie
AND pdg_matriculas.id_turma = pdg_turma.id_turma');
$this->db->limit(10);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

tried with Active Record and also failed

```
$this->db->select('T1.id_matricula, T2.nome_aluno, T3.nome_serie, T4.nome_turma, T2.status_aluno, T1.ano_letivo',FALSE);
$this->db->from('pdg_matriculas T1, aluno T2, pdg_serie T3, pdg_turma T4');
$this->db->where('T1.id_matricula','T2.id_aluno');
$this->db->where('T1.id_serie','T3.id_serie');
$this->db->where('T1.id_turma','T4.id_turma');
$this->db->order_by('T2.nome_aluno', 'asc'); 
$this->db->limit(10);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Can anyone help me convert to Active Record?

Thanks!

Comment: print your last query **echo $this->db->last_query();**

Comment: For Direct Query use, **$result = $this->db->query("your query");  return $result->result();**

Comment: Did you have any chance to take a look at **[CI documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)**?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did not know this way with last_query () shows nothing more unfortunately, I will keep trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay, now it worked, of course a few minor changes, more myth thanks to everyone and keep your reference.

```
$this->db->select('T1.id_matricula,aluno.nome_aluno,pdg_serie.nome_serie,pdg_turma.nome_turma,T1.ano_letivo,T1.id_aluno as id_aluno_m,aluno.id_aluno as id_aluno_a,aluno.status_aluno');
$this->db->from('pdg_matriculas T1');
$this->db->join('aluno', 'aluno.id_aluno = T1.id_aluno');
$this->db->join('pdg_serie', 'pdg_serie.id_serie = T1.id_serie');
$this->db->join('pdg_turma', 'pdg_turma.id_turma = T1.id_turma');
$page_data ['alunos_lista'] = $this->db->get ()->result_array ();
```

Worked Perfect

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
 $this->db->select('T1.id_matricula, T2.nome_aluno, T3.nome_serie, T4.nome_turma, T2.status_aluno, T1.ano_letivo',FALSE);
    $this->db->from('pdg_matriculas as T1');
    $this->db->join('aluno as T2','T1.id_matricula = T2.id_aluno');   
    $this->db->join('pdg_serie as T3','T1.id_serie = T3.id_serie');
    $this->db->join('pdg_turma as T4','T1.id_turma = T4.id_turma');
    $this->db->order_by('T2.nome_aluno', 'asc'); 
    $this->db->limit(10);
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Thank you.
I swore that was the answer was very logical my mistake, unfortunately did not work out, the more I think it'll work on the join line to resolve this query.                                                        Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2

SELECT * FROM (`0`, `8`, `)

Comment: This line was wrong, but still the error continues, more is another mistake.
        $this->db->join('aluno T2','T1.id_aluno = T2.id_aluno');  Error Number: 1064


SELECT T1.id_matricula, T2.nome_aluno, T3.nome_serie, T4.nome_turma, T2.status_aluno, T1.ano_letivo FROM (`pdg_matriculas` T1) JOIN `aluno` T2,T1.id_aluno = T2.id_aluno ON JOIN `pdg_serie` T3,T1.id_serie = T3.id_serie ON JOIN `pdg_turma` T4,T1.id_turma = T4.id_turma ON ORDER BY `T2`.`nome_aluno` asc LIMIT 10